# How to do channel interceptor based on pattern using JAVA DSL in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

We are planning to migrate our code from Spring integration XML to DSL. In XML Version, we are using channel name pattern to do tracing.

For Eg: If channel name has `*_EL_*`, we intercept the channel and do some logging.

How to do this kind or more simpler in Java dsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` is for you. And it is a part of Spring Integration Core.

So, you must do something like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel bar() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "*_EL_*")
public WireTap baz() {
    return new WireTap(this.bar());
}
```

I mean specify the `ChannelInterceptor` `@Bean` and mark it with that annotation to make pattern-based interceptions.

**UPDATE**

The sample test-case which demonstrate the work for `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` for the `auto-created` channel from DSL flows:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class SO31573744Tests {

    @Autowired
    private TestGateway testGateway;

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel intercepted;

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        this.testGateway.testIt("foo");
        Message<?> receive = this.intercepted.receive(1000);
        assertNotNull(receive);
        assertEquals("foo", receive.getPayload());
    }


    @MessagingGateway
    public interface TestGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "testChannel")
        void testIt(String payload);

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    @IntegrationComponentScan
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                    .channel("nullChannel")
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public PollableChannel intercepted() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        @Bean
        @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "*Ch*")
        public WireTap wireTap() {
            return new WireTap(intercepted());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have the *_EL_* interceptor configured in xml. But below is not intercepting by the interceptor. Any Idea?

IntegrationFlows.from("pushAssetId_EL_Channel")
   .transform(new UpdateMetaDataTransformer())

Comment: It does not make sense for me. Please, share your config to convince us that we have a bug. And we will try to provide you the workaround. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/manojp1988/Learning/tree/JavaDSL/Sample1

if I call xmlGateway, xml interceptor working. If i call java dsl gateway, java interceptor is calling but not both.

Comment: Please, find an update in my answer and confirm that it works for you, too. And try with the latest `DSL-1.0.2` version, BTW. It works for me on `1.0.3` from the `master`

Comment: In my above example, why xml interceptor class was not called when i hit dsl gateway?. I understand the part @GlobalChannelInterceptor but it is intercepting only java dsl channel.